# change runtime created element style

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

i have 5 element those created at run time like these

```
NewButton := TImageViewer.Create(Self);
    with NewButton do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Bitmap.LoadFromStream(InStream);
      Height := 80;
      Width := 80;
      tag:=leftx;
      Position.X := leftx;
      Position.Y := 5;
      OnClick := WaitingButtonsClick;
      Enabled := True;
      Visible := True;
      Name := 'but' + IntToStr(leftx);
    end;
leftx := leftx+85;
```

so elements have their own name and tag

now after user clicked the image i have to change the loaded image

so i got the name on element after click

```
procedure TForm1.WaitingButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
// ShowMessage( (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent.Name );
   ShowMessage(TImageViewer(Sender).Name);
 // id := TButton(Sender).tag;
 // showmessage('slm'+id.ToString);
end;
```

ok.after getting the name of element how can i change the target file or style!?

Comment: I am confused, why you are casting something of class `TImageViewer` to `TButton`?

Comment: Delphi XE has no class named `TImageViewer`. That's an FMX class. What version of Delphi are you actually using?

Comment: @quasoft sorry, my mistake.. updated now!

Comment: Please fix the question tagging

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fixed

Comment: I retagged. You want both the generic delphi tag, and a version specific one. Thanks.

Comment: you can change `TImageViewer(Sender).height` or any other style easily with style name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are casting an object of type `TImageViewer` to `TButton`.

Change your click handler like that:

```
procedure TForm1.WaitingButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  viewer: TImageViewer;
begin
  viewer := Sender as TImageViewer;

  // Change file or style of viewer
  //viewer.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(....);

  ...
end;
```

---

As a rule, always cast objects with `as` operator:

`viewer := Sender as TImageViewer` - RIGHT

vs

`viewer := TImageViewer(Sender)` - WRONG

The benefit is that `as` operator performs safety checks for you, and warns you if you are trying to cast to incompatible type.

The second variant can only be used if the variable is plain pointer (not an object), and that is rarely required.

---

Also using position on form to make component names unique is not recommended.

Its better to come up with another scheme for component name creation.

For example, you can define a counter in the form and add that counter to the names of the components.